# Run OdooLocust in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to perform load test using OdooLocust module. When I try to run I am getting below error:

```
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,395] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr: Traceback (most recent call last): 
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,395] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr: File "/usr/local/bin/locust", line 11, in <module> 
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,395] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr:  
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,395] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr: sys.exit(main()) [2019-03-01 16:21:52,395] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr:  
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,395] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/locust/main.py", line 391, in main [2019-03-01 16:21:52,396] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr:  
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,396] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr: docstring, locusts = load_locustfile(locustfile) 
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,396] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr:  
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,396] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/locust/main.py", line 358, in load_locustfile 
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,396] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr:  
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,396] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr: imported =
    __import__(os.path.splitext(locustfile)[0]) 
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,396] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr:  
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,396] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr: File "/home/user/Desktop/seller_taskset.py", line 2, in <module> 
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,396] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr:  
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,396] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr: from OdooLocust import OdooLocust 
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,396] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr:  
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,396] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/OdooLocust/OdooLocust.py", line 45 [2019-03-01 16:21:52,396] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr:  
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,396] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr: except Exception, e: 
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,397] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr: ^ 
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,397] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr: SyntaxError 
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,397] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr: : 
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,397] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr: invalid syntax
[2019-03-01 16:21:52,397] lenovo-v330-kbir/ERROR/stderr:
```

Here is the command:

```
 sudo locust -f seller_taskset.py Seller
```

Python Version:

```
 python -V

 Python 2.7.15rc1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question you are showing that system Python version is `2.7.15rc1` but from stack trace it is clear that `locust` is installed and running with Python version 3.6, often running python2.7 codes with python3 causes syntax error as there are significant differences between those two version syntax.

The particular script you are running, requires python 2.7 to be run. Install python `virtualenv`, create a virtual environment with python2.7 with following command:

```
virtualenv -p python venv
```

Install requirements:

```
./venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Now run your python script:

```
./venv/bin/locust -f seller_taskset.py Seller
```

*Also you trying to run locust with sudo, I don't think that is necessary.*